# Using multilist column as foreign key reference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `TABLEA` that store data in a Columns which are basically multilist columns like this `ColumnA` ',2562,2563,2564,' and `ColumnB` with values `',121,122,123,'`.
These column are actually foreign key values coming from another table.

Data is something like this in Table A.

```
ID NAME   ColumnA           ColumnB
1  ITEM1  ,2562,2563,2564,  ,121,122,123
2  ITEM2  NULL              ,6455,545,
3  ITEM3  ,1221,1546,       NULL
4  ITEM4  NULL              NULL
```

I want to join these columns with there parent tables and extract data.
I am hoping the result set would have 8 rows.
For example

```
ITEM   ColumnA   ColumB
ITEM1  2562      121
ITEM1  2563      122
ITEM1  2564      123
ITEM2  NULL      6455
ITEM2  NULL      545
....
```

I have tried this query with some help but this is not working when I try to use `ColumnB` as well and also it ignores the Items with `NULL` values.
The Column A is saving Ids of `USER_GROUP` table but `ColumnB` is fetching the Ids from some other table lets say `GROUP1` and there could be another Column `ColumnC` that might be storing values from another table so that's kind of situation I am stuck in and hope I have explained so someone can understand but I am open if you want me to improve more

```
SELECT ug.*
FROM USER_GROUP ug
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableA t1
              WHERE t1.COLUMNA LIKE '%,' || ug.ID || ',%'
             )
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableA t1
              WHERE t1.COLUMNB LIKE '%,' || ug.ID || ',%'
             );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, name, cola, colb) as
  2    (select 1, 'item1', ',2562,2563,2564,', ',121,122,123,' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'item2', null              , ',6455,545,'    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'item3', ',1221,1546,'     , null            from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'item4', null              , null            from dual
  6    ),
  7  remcom
  8    -- remove leading and trailing commas
  9  as (select id,
 10        name,
 11        rtrim(ltrim(cola, ','), ',') cola,
 12        rtrim(ltrim(colb, ','), ',') colb
 13      from test
 14     )
 15  select id,
 16    name,
 17    regexp_substr(cola, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) cola,
 18    regexp_substr(colb, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) colb
 19  from remcom r cross join
 20    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 21                        connect by level <= regexp_count(nvl(r.cola, r.colb), ',') + 1
 22                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 23  order by id, name, cola, colb;

        ID NAME  COLA       COLB
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 item1 2562       121
         1 item1 2563       122
         1 item1 2564       123
         2 item2            545
         2 item2            6455
         3 item3 1221
         3 item3 1546
         4 item4

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now that you have it, join this result with another table you have.

By the way, this example nicely shows what it is a bad idea to store multiple values into the same column. Don't do that.

Comment: I agree with you that's it's really not a good practice but changing the table structure is not in my hands so I am stuck with this approach and have to do this at all cost.

Comment: I know; usually we can't do much about it.

Comment: So if I have another column I would just put it in connect by command like this
`connect by level <= regexp_count(nvl(nvl(r.cola, r.colb), r.colc), ',') + 1` after formatting above as well ?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use (slow) regular expressions and can do it with simple string functions in a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH split_data ( id, name, columna, columnb, starta, enda, startb, endb ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         columna,
         columnb,
         INSTR(columna,',',1,1),
         INSTR(columna,',',1,2),
         INSTR(columnb,',',1,1),
         INSTR(columnb,',',1,2)
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         name,
         columna,
         columnb,
         enda,
         CASE WHEN enda = 0 THEN 0 ELSE INSTR(columna,',',enda+1,1) END,
         endb,
         CASE WHEN endb = 0 THEN 0 ELSE INSTR(columnb,',',endb+1,1) END
  FROM   split_data
  WHERE  enda > 0
  OR     endb > 0
)
SELECT id,
       name,
       CASE
       WHEN starta = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN enda = 0 THEN SUBSTR( columna, starta + 1 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( columna, starta + 1, enda - starta - 1 )
       END AS valuea,
       CASE
       WHEN startb = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN endb = 0 THEN SUBSTR( columnb, startb + 1 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( columnb, startb + 1, endb - startb - 1 )
       END as valueb
FROM   split_data
ORDER BY id, starta, startb;
```

Which for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( ID, NAME, ColumnA, ColumnB ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ITEM1', ',2562,2563,2564', ',121,122,123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ITEM2', NULL,              ',6455,545' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ITEM3', ',1221,1546',      NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ITEM4', NULL,              NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | NAME  | VALUEA | VALUEB
> -: | :---- | :----- | :-----
>  1 | ITEM1 | 2562   | 121   
>  1 | ITEM1 | 2563   | 122   
>  1 | ITEM1 | 2564   | 123   
>  2 | ITEM2 | null   | 6455  
>  2 | ITEM2 | null   | 545   
>  3 | ITEM3 | 1221   | null  
>  3 | ITEM3 | 1546   | null  
>  4 | ITEM4 | null   | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec1d685de77fa5c00920f702c089615d)*